# Private data on a public cloud challenges and best practices

Tags: security, cloud

So far most of our clients (online retailers and banks) have been reticent of placing any parts of theirs applications to a public cloud, although this could be a very cost effective manner to deal with temporary demand upsurge (end of month, holidays etc.)

We could place middle tier on a cloud so that no information is persisted in the cloud, or so that only non-sensitive data is stored there.

What are the best practices in this case? 
Are there any regulations that I should be aware?
What are the biggest threats?

Comment: There is no way that I would recommend a bank to use a public cloud except for already publicly available data... the threats are just too many - just some examples: someone working for the cloud provider accesses the data, some disk drives being "recycled" and turning up on ebay, some backdoor in the encryption...what sort of data are we talking about ? and what is the sense in using a cloud if you "place a middle tier on a cloud so nothing is persisted in the cloud" ????

Comment: @Yahia I am thinking of placing the online banking application on the cloud that connects to the bank backend. Persistance layer stays in bank, but web servers are on the cloud.

Comment: IMHO this is a very bad idea... even without the persistence: the application needs to contain lots of information about the access to the backend - very valuable information for anyone wanting to "get into the bank"... another point is the cloud provider would be able to intercept any communication (even with SSL)... phishing becomes alot easier if you host the banking application in a public cloud... who is liable if anything bad happens ? the cloud provider ? you ? the bank ? (check back with as many real top-notch lawyers before speaking to any bank)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use cryptography.

You have the choice of public key cryptography: encrypt your data with a public key, put it "on ze cloud", then when you retrieve it, decrypt with your private key. Even better, if the data only transits through you, you can only have the public key and only your client has the private key.

Or symmetric cryptography, in which case you need the key, which will help encrypt and decrypt.

Symmetric cryptography algorithms are much faster, but if the scenario I mentioned above applies (ie, the client can have the private key), definitely go for it: you won't even be able to read the data without the client's consent.